# MySQL need to return table with NULL id's

Tags: mysql

I have a table same to this

| id | number | id_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | NULL |
| 2 | 002 | NULL |
| 1 | 001 | 13 |

id_user is a fk to users table, but it should be empty while user will be assigned
how do i can get all info from table with id_user and without it? if i create

```
select number 
from user, incident 
where incident.id_user = user.id or incident.id_user is null
```

i got a wrong info

Comment: Please add both table description, sample data, expected results and MySQL version, all in text format. And switch to current/proper join syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a left join to include null values:

```
select * from user left join incident on incident.id_user=user.id
```

alternatively:

```
select number 
from user, incident 
where incident.id_user(+) = user.id
```